# Passing by reference and assigning into a variable

Tags: pass-by-reference

I was studying about passing by reference. It made me wonder what would happen in the following example (Written in pseudo-C which supports "by reference"):

```
int foo(int a) {
    a = 5;
    return a * 2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    a = foo(a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

What should be printed? if we only did `foo(a);` without assigning into `a` then we would get `5`. but what would be printed when assigning? should it be `5` or `10`?

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Comment: Since you're imagining a psuedo-C that has pass-by-reference, you'll have to decide for yourself what the semantics associated with argument passing will be.  I don't see how you can expect *us* to answer that, at least not in a way appropriate for SO.

Comment: Until you give semantics for `pasudo-C` language for "by reference" variable passing, there is no one that can answer that question.

Comment: Why do you have to hypothesize about a pseudo-C?  Why not ask about, say, `a = foo(&a);` with `int foo(int* a) { *a = 5; return *a * 2; }`?  Or perhaps ask about C++ where you could have `int foo(int& a)`?

Comment: Removed the `C` tag. I thought there is only one way possible and if not it will be more helpful to see explanation for the difference, benefits and maybe a real PL which uses it. I don't think it's a question "opinion-based" but sorry if it is.

Comment: First a is set to 5. Then 10 is returned. Then a is set to 10. There is no ambiguity.

Comment: @vesii: You are only going to confuse readers and yourself by using C syntax and declare it to be pseudocode, and that the syntax should be interpreted as pass by reference. In my experience, pseudocode that wants to specify a function with pass by reference parameters use a declarative syntax with textual descriptions like: `foo(integer a : in/out, string b : in, string c : out) ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: Although the close reason is too broad, I had voted to close the question as a duplicate. See the linked question. The assignment occurs after the function call completes, so there is no ambiguity, as was commented by @immibis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `a = foo(a);` in your `main()` function, `a` will contain the result returned by `foo(a)`.  `foo(a)` will always return 10 no matter what `a` is.

C does not support pass by reference. Changing `a = foo(a);` to just `foo(a);` would mean `a` would retain the value it had before it was passed to `foo()`, so it would be 1.

One variation of C that supports pass by reference is C++. In C++, you could write `foo()` as:

```
int foo(int &a) {
    a = 5;
    return a * 2;
}
```

The `int &a` syntax is used to denote that the parameter will be passed by reference. Now, `foo` will assign 5 to the referenced variable, but still always return 10.

In this case `a = foo(a);` will result in `a` having the value 10, and `foo(a);` alone will result in `a` having the value 5.

Comment: He's talking about "pseudocode" in a C-like form, not C. But pseudocode is entirely subjective. I flagged his question for being opinion-based.

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger: I agree that precise interpretation of pseudocode may be subjective. However, it is the lingua franca for specifying algorithms, so it should be possible to reason about it without being considered opinion-based.